# tf__norm() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I a trying to pass a function to my tf dataset to normalize the non numerical data in my data frame, however I keep getting this error:

TypeError: in user code:
TypeError: tf__norm() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
def norm(dataframe):
    for header in dataframe._get_numeric_data().columns:
        dataframe[header] = (dataframe[header] - dataframe[header].mean())/dataframe[header].std()
    return dataframe

train, val= train_test_split( dataframe, test_size =0.2)

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    labels = dataframe.pop("target")
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds=ds.map(norm)
    return ds

    
train_ds=  df_to_dataset(train, shuffle=False, batch_size=32) 
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow your code, the type of *ds* is BatchDataSet , Its element_spec is tuple which size is 2, but your norm function only needs one parameter, That's why it raise

`takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

More detail, the type of first elements is dict, the other is TensorSpec. So just update your norm function like this:

```
def norm(df_as_dict, tensor_spec):
    ...
    do some work for df_as_dict
    ...
```